# Replacing Phone Internal Camera with Video Footage using v4l2loopback

Tags: v4l2loopback

I'm currently exploring the possibility of replacing my phone's internal camera feed with video footage using v4l2loopback. My goal is to have applications on my phone use a predefined video as if it were the live camera feed.

I have a few questions:

Procedure: Could someone guide me through the steps to achieve this using v4l2loopback? Any specific commands or configurations I need to be aware of?

Application Compatibility: Will this replacement apply to all apps that use the camera, or are there limitations? I'm particularly interested in knowing if common camera-dependent applications will seamlessly work with the video feed.

Comment: why are you limiting the options to v4l2loopback?

Comment: @jsotola, whats other way you got?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you faced problems. Otherwise, the question might be closed as asking for a tutorial, which is [off-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).